# D3 Tree Graph - How to transition links when using straight line, not diagonal

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, hierarchy, graphing

I am working with this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f1nzagyw/

I want to change the example from diagonal to straight lines, which I have been able to do but when I click on a node to expand or shorten the graph, the old links aren't being removed from the graph, so I end up with multiple links. Can someone please advise on how I can transition the original links, using straight lines, with the transitioning nodes? It seemed to change when I moved from diagonal to straight lines.

I added the lineFunction and used it in the links as you can see in the fiddle,:

```
     var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
        .interpolate("linear");
```

I also appended the "line" and the x/y coordinates:

```
 var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.x; });
```

Also, what's the best way to keep the links behind the nodes, so that the links run behind the nodes, not in front? I thought I just needed to put the code for the links above the nodes but that doesn't seem to be working.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1**

*The old links are not getting updated*

You  are doing:

```
var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links)
```

This is wrong because there is no `path` DOM there is a `line` DOM so you are selection is wrong.

You should be doing:

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
```

**Problem 2**

*The best way to keep the links behind the nodes:*

First create links and then create nodes so now the links will appear behind nodes.

```
//create link first
link.enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", lineFunction)
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    });;

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit()
    .remove();
   //create nodes
  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);
```

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/q1a6o1o8/)

**EDIT**

To ensure that nodes are always on the top make two groups.

```
var svglink = svg.append("g");//add links inside this group
var svgnode = svg.append("g");//add nodes inside this group
```

Now when you make links do this to ensure that they are on below the nodes.

```
  // Update the links…
  var link = svglink.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svgnode.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });
```

working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/q1a6o1o8/1/)

Comment: @Cyril..awesome thanks for the time. One thing..it looks like the links sit behind the nodes initially but once a node is clicked on to expand or collapse the graph the links move to the front of the nodes again..is it possible to keep them behind the nodes at all times?

Comment: all looks great when I remove the collapse feature (root.children.forEach(collapse);) so that the whole graph is showing right away but expanding/collapsing is pushing the links in front of the nodes

Comment: yeah it had an issue ....fixed the problem check my edit section I have fixed it now :)

Comment: Perfect thanks. I was working to expand on your example and made some additions but also hit a couple more issues. I posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932405/d3-tree-graph-text-center-controlling-height-and-link-arrow-odd-behavior .If you have any time to take a look help is appreciated. Thanks again for your help here.