# D3 Tree Graph - Text Center, Controlling Height, and Link Arrow Odd Behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, graph, hierarchy

I am working on a D3 Tree Graph with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q1a6o1o8/2/

I am having some issues with the following:

1. I can't seem to properly center the text inside the rectangle nodes. I haven't had a problem when using circles. "text-anchor" "middle' isn't working. I'm trying to avoid using the "x" attribute to center so that the text is always centered inside the "rect" regardless of its length.
2. Is there a way to make the rectangles responsive so that basically the width or height of the rectangle changes based on the length of the text included? i.e. longer text should stay centered inside the "rect" node
3. I've added Arrow icons on the links but I am getting weird behavior in regards to having them appear. If you click around on the fiddle you'll see the arrows will appear in some cases but not appear in others?
4. How can I adjust the distance between each node up and down (not depth). Reason I ask is when I expand the graph all the way out, the leaf nodes seem to be overlapping each other. When I increase the height of the svg container to 900 that seems to help but the other nodes are expanded too far away from each other earlier in the graph. Is there a way to keep the parent nodes closer together but keep the leaf nodes from overlapping without increasing the SVG height?

   ```
   var height = 900; //changed from 650
   ```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1: Since `text-anchor` is a style, you have to use the following:

```
nodeEnter.append("text").style("text-anchor", "middle")
```

You'll notice that this will set the text to be centered on the left edge of the `rect`. You can fix this by offsetting either the `text` or the `rect` element by half the width of the `rect`.

2: This too is fairly simple. After drawing the text elements you would want to run through them (`each` function), select their respective `rect` (should be possible using the `d` parameter), and then set the width of the `rect` to be the calculated width.

```
svg.selectAll("text").each(function (d){
var textWidth = this.getBBox().width;
});
```

3: Move `.attr("marker-end", "url(#arrowhead)")` to the end of `link.enter().append("line")` (after you set `y2`).

4: The easiest way is to increase the tree height, such as `var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([1500, width]);` and then enable zooming and dragging ([example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708)). You could theoretically customize the depth spacing, but it would likely be more work than zoom/drag. Another option is to add `.nodeSize([50,return 50;}])` to `var tree = ...`, but this changes the spacing for all nodes regardless of depth. Note that setting `nodeSize` overrides `size` and causes the tree to automatically change size based on the number of nodes.

Comment: Thanks JSBob. #3 is good to go. For #1 how exactly to I offset the text to move the text in the middle? I tried using transform/translate but that didn't work. And for #2, I am getting the text width but where exactly does that need to go in my code as I'm declaring the rect before the text..so do I have to reset the width of the rect after getting the text width, and do I have to do that for the enter, and translate states? It seems like I would have to set the width of the rect then inside of the selectAll statement you have so that I can access the textWidth variable?

Comment: You can use `.attr("x", <int>)` to offset the text. For #2 the way I would do it is run through the `g.node` elements and for each one, get the `rect` and `text` element. Then get the width of the `text` element and set the `width` of the `rect` and the `x` of the `text`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/armarchm/q1a6o1o8/3/) is a link which has this. See lines 200-210.

Comment: Great, thanks. #1 and #2 look great. I've been working on #4 and had just a couple more questions then I'll mark as answer and move on...I think nodeSize is what I want but I'm getting syntax errors when I use the code you have in your answer, did you mean to put the return statement and the "}" in there? Most examples online I see .nodeSize([50,50]) but when I use that my nodes move off the svg? I was also working to add drag and zoom features, I think the zoom is working but I guess I'm not sure what exactly I should be looking for there?

Comment: For the drag, can you tell me exactly how I can incorporate the the code  on lines 111-125 into what I have? I'm a little confused there. I commented it out for now. It doesn't look like I need to make any other adjustments to the "container" code from what I can tell? I've updated the fiddle to what I have at this point: http://jsfiddle.net/q1a6o1o8/20/ - nodeSize is active in this fiddle and what is moving it outside of the svg